# PropertyInfo.GetValue failing on a custom class

Tags: xna, c#, reflection

I have an object, `RenderComponent`, that has a property named `Model` that is of type `StaticModel`. When I get the `PropertyInfo` of my `RenderComponent` and then call `GetValue()` on it, it is giving me a TargetException, saying "Object does not match target type."

I'll write a small sample of code to give you the gist of what is failing. Here's the hierarchy:

```
public class RenderComponent
{
    StaticModel Model;
}

public class StaticModel
{

}
```

And I'm essentially doing this:

```
RenderComponent renderComponent = new RenderComponent();
PropertyInfo[] props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);

foreach (PropertyInfo info in props)
{
    // I get the exception here
    Object value = info.GetValue(renderComponent, null);
}
```

My program is of course much more complicated, but I still don't see how it could be failing. I must be missing something simple.

I get the exception on this line:

`info.GetValue(obj, null)`

Where `info` is the `PropertyInfo` of `StaticModel`, and `obj` is an instantiated `RenderComponent`. When I stop at this exception and do a watch on obj, I can actual step through the hierarchy until I get to my StaticModel value, and it exists and has the data I would expect.

I'm sure if I took the small code sample I posted in this thread it would work fine, so it has to be something with how I'm calling it within my engine, I just don't see how GetValue can fail when obj clearly has that value within it.

**Here's a screenshot of me debugging 'obj' and finding the StaticModel:**
[image]

**And here's the error I get:**
[image]

**And here you can see the values of `obj` and `info`, as proof that my object instance I'm passing is a RenderComponent, and the PropertyInfo I'm calling GetValue on is a Static Model (which is a member of RenderComponent, as you can see in the first image:**
[image]

Comment: Sorry, where's the value of `info`? You're showing obj both times, even if you have searched for info in the second capture.

Comment: Why does obj (in last Watch screenshot) has Key & Value? isn't supposed to be a RenderComponent ? I think you are passing a KeyValuePair instead of a RenderComponent instance

Comment: Right, pass obj.Value instead.

Comment: @sos00 I think you may be right, the components in my engine are in a dictionary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sos00's comment from the original question was the correct answer to this question. His comment was:

> Why does obj (in last Watch screenshot) has Key & Value? isn't supposed to be a RenderComponent ? I think you are passing a KeyValuePair instead of a RenderComponent instance